# Error in mx.sym.Reshape() from http://mxnet.io/tutorials/nlp/cnn.html

Tags: python, convolution, text-classification, mxnet

I'm trying to follow the **Text Classification Tutorial** on http://mxnet.io/tutorials/nlp/cnn.html

Until I call the function:

```
conv_input = mx.sym.Reshape(data=embed_layer, target_shape=(batch_size, 1, sentence_size, num_embed))
```

everything goes well. But then I get the error:

> conv_input = mx.sym.Reshape(data=embed_layer, target_shape=(batch_size, 1, sentence_size, num_embed))
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Users\my.name\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\mxnet-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\mxnet\symbol.py", line 1062, in creator
>       ctypes.byref(sym_handle)))
>     File "C:\Users\my.name\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.10.3\python-2.7.10.amd64\lib\site-packages\mxnet-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\mxnet\base.py", line 77, in check_call
>       raise MXNetError(py_str(_LIB.MXGetLastError()))
>   mxnet.base.MXNetError: Invalid Parameter format for target_shape expect Shape(tuple) but value='(50, 1, 56L, 300)'

Does anyone have an idea, How to make this work?

Comment: recheck everything, works well on my side...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your symbol.py file is not the updated version. Maybe rebuild mxnet with the latest version?